# Map 2D data to a room plan?

Tags: visualization

I need to map 2D measures taken at regular intervals in a room on the room floor plan in order to create a "heat map". Something like that:

[image] 
<sup>Taken from https://www.purrmetrix.com/category/advice/ -- for illustration purpose only</sup>

The room map can reasonably accurately be rendered as a polygon. However, I can't find:

- how to create the continuous "heat map" from discrete samples (using bilinear interpolation between the samples),
- nor how to put the room plan on the map, ensuring the "heat map" is *clipped* by the room boundaries.

I saw Mathematica has a [full range of primitives to work with maps](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/MapsAndCartography.html). But it seems there are more suitable to work with geodata, rather than simple 2D plans.

I didn't find really useful answers by searching on the net, probably because I lack the right keywords. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Mapping functionality is for geographic computation. I doubt that it would apply easily here. Perhaps model the room as a `Polygon`, then generate a `RegionMemberFunction` from it, using `RegionMember`. Then use `ListDensityPlot` with that `RegionMemberFunction` as a `RegionFunction` option. If you had sample data, this would be easier to explain.

Comment: @Marco I've completely missed [ListDensityPlot](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListDensityPlot.html) in the doc :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I mentioned in comments that I doubted that the mapping functionality would be appropriate here, but an easier approach would be to model the room as a `Polygon`, then generate and save `RegionMemberFunction` from it, using `RegionMember`. I would then use `ListDensityPlot` to present your data, with that `RegionMemberFunction` as a [`RegionFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionFunction.html) option. Here is an example of the approach I mentioned in comments, using some made up data.

First, generate the room outline as a `Polygon` and the corresponding [`RegionMemberFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionMemberFunction.html), as well as some fake data in the form $(x,y,value)$:

```
room = Polygon[{{0, 0}, {6, 0}, {6, 2}, {2, 2}, {2, 4}, {0, 4}}];
rmf = RegionMember[room];
fakedata = Table[{x, y, Sin[x] Cos[y]}, {x, -1., 8}, {y, -1., 5}]~Flatten~1;
```

Plot the data within the polygon, adding the `room` polygon as an outline:

```
Show[
  Graphics[
    {FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Directive[Thickness[0.01], Black]], room},
    AspectRatio -> Automatic
  ],
  ListDensityPlot[
    fakedata,
    RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, rmf[{x, y}]],
    MaxPlotPoints -> 60
  ]
]
```

[image: room and density plot]

The [`MaxPlotPoints`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxPlotPoints.html) option within `ListDensityPlot` increases the precision of the drawing so that the density plot hews more closely to the shape of the room (the sharp corner was otherwise causing trouble).

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Marco. I didn't expect such a detailed answer: this was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Sylvain Great! Glad to hear that.